# How to convert firebase time stamp to Millisecond?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud firestore to store data.
I want to convert timestamp field data to Millisecond.

Data I am getting in below format

```
{"nanoseconds": 627000000, "seconds": 1647432933}
```

I want to convert it to Millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore have a method called `toMillis()`. You can use it like this. See code below:

```
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("timestamp:", docSnap.data().timestamp.toMillis());
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
```

will return something like this:

```
timestamp: 1647438836443
```

For more information, you may refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#tomillis).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in for Firebase V8.

```js
 const getServerTime = () =>
firebase.firestore?.Timestamp?.now().toMillis();
```